# Controlling step motor using arrows

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, curses

I'm doing a program on a raspberry pi with which I can control a motor using the keyboard arrows. For that, I used from GPIO Zero module as the example for the Keyboard control robot. I managed to update the code for my needing, but when I'm pressing the keys, nothing is happening.

Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance

For controlling the step motors I'm using the Adafruit module.

```
import curses
import time
from gpiozero import Robot
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit

kit = ServoKit(channels=8)

            
def cameraDown():
        kit.servo[0].angle = 0
        time.sleep(0.01)
        
def cameraUp():
        kit.servo[0].angle = 180
        time.sleep(0.01)
        
def cameraFront():
        kit.servo[0].angle = 90
        time.sleep(0.01)
        
def cameraFace():
        kit.servo[0].angle = 70
        time.sleep(0.01)

actions = {
    curses.KEY_UP:  cameraDown(),
    curses.KEY_DOWN:    cameraUp(),
    curses.KEY_LEFT:    cameraFront(),
    curses.KEY_RIGHT:   cameraFace(),
}



def main(window):
    next_key = None
    while True:
        curses.halfdelay(1)
        if next_key is None:
            key = window.getch()
        else:
            key = next_key
            next_key = None
        if key != -1:
            # KEY PRESSED
            curses.halfdelay(3)
            action = actions.get(key)
            if action is not None:
                action()
            next_key = key
            while next_key == key:
                next_key = window.getch()
            # KEY RELEASED
            cameraFace()


curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: What ways have you tried to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `actions` dict, where you give each key the value returned by one of the functions. What you mean to do here is to give it the function itself. Just take the parentheses off:

```
actions = {
    curses.KEY_UP:  cameraDown,
    curses.KEY_DOWN:    cameraUp,
    curses.KEY_LEFT:    cameraFront,
    curses.KEY_RIGHT:   cameraFace
}
```